# Angular Js navigation issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement simple login functionality and getting

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

exception. What does it mean? and how can i navigate to home page once I get successful response

I tried:

```
$location.path('/home')
$location.path('/home').apply()
$scope.$apply();
```

and many more things.

how can i create session or maintain user detail, throughout the session.
Here is my loginApp module code.

```
angular.module('loginApp', [])                                                                                 
    .config([                                                                     
    '$httpProvider','$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',                                 
    function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {  
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/login.html',
            controller: LoginController
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: LoginController
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 

    }                                                                         
])
    .factory('Auth',['$http',
        function($http){
            return {
                login: function(inputs) {
                    return $http.post('API_URL', inputs);
                }
             }
    }])
    .controller('LoginController',['$scope', '$http', 'Auth', '$location', function($scope, $http, Auth, $location) {
        $scope.loginUser = function() {
            Auth.login({
                email: $scope.login.email,
                Password: $scope.login.password,
                APIkey: 'API_KEY'
            }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $scope.login.msg  = "Please your username and password";
                } else {
                 //   $rootScope.user = user;
                        $scope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/home"); });
                    $scope.login.msg  = "You are logged in successfully.";
                }
            }).error(function(data) {
                 $scope.login.msg  = "Error in Response.";

            });

        },
      $scope.logout = function() {
          // user is logged out
        //  $rootScope.user = null;
     }
    }]);
```

My HTML code login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en" data-ng-app="loginApp"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en" data-ng-app="loginApp"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" data-ng-app="loginApp"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html lang="en" data-ng-app="loginApp"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html data-ng-app="loginApp"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="JSON/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="widget/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="home.html"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home"/></a></li> 
          <li><a href="upload.html"><img src="images/upload.png" alt="job_posting"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="download.html"><img src="images/list.png" alt="download"/></a></li> 
        </ul>
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="dialogicalogo" alt="Dialogica"/> 
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="login" data-ng-controller="LoginController">
      <div id="content_header">
        <img src="images/login.png" alt="job_posting"/>
        <h1>User Login</h1>
      </div>
      <form>
        <p>{{ login.msg }}</p>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" value="email" data-ng-model="login.email" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='email';" onfocus="if(this.value=='email') this.value='';" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password">Password</label><a href="help.html" class="help">[Forgot?]</a>
          <input type="password" id="password" value="Password" data-ng-model="login.password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Password';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Password') this.value='';" />
        </div>

      </form>
      <a href="#" data-ng-click="loginUser()" class="button blue center">Log in</a>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="widget/js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular-cookies.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
    <script src="widget/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The main application script -->
    <script src="widget/js/services/auth.js"></script>
    <script src="widget/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="widget/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            // Invoke the plugin
            $('input, textarea').placeholder();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One question are you using angular-ui-router?

Comment: no...but just now i put ut in my code..it is throwing javascript exception

Comment: updated my code..it is throwing javascript exception

Comment: one more thing, is it mandatory to include <div data-ng-view=""></div> tag to make it work? I am not including it in my HTML

Comment: yes thats mandatory... else where will the view be displayed??

Comment: yes it is like a placeholder for your different templates. Think of a single page app having multiple templates to render and this is the place where it will change

Comment: yes..but i have one doubt..in my HTML i already have login page hTML code...so i can't put this view tag inside this HTML. am i right? I have to create one index.html to render all the pages and this index.html will have only ng-view tag. am i right?

Comment: You have to create an index.html and have the ng-view inside the body tag. You can create a login template and can have a route for login as well

Comment: @V31 can you please help me online? using webex or teamviewer?

Comment: Certainly however I in middle of something can it wait till Tomorrow?

Comment: :( actually tommorrow is deadline for this project and I need to finish it by today. If possible we can sit late night also

Comment: It must not take much time..few silly mistakes would be the problem...if possible try to find out some time today itself

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. In your controller you have applied scope.apply which is irrelevant and should not be used over there. And second you your location.path will work if scope.apply is not applied
Update: $routeParams dependency should be included before $location dependency

```
.controller('LoginController',['$scope', '$http', 'Auth', '$routeParams','$location',function($scope, $http, Auth,$routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.loginUser = function() {
            Auth.login({
                email: $scope.login.email,
                Password: $scope.login.password,
                APIkey: 'API_KEY'
            }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $scope.login.msg  = "Please your username and password";
                } else {
                 //   $rootScope.user = user;
                 // No Apply method required
  //$scope.$apply(function() { 
                 $location.path("/home");
                 $scope.login.msg  = "You are logged in successfully.";
             }
            }).error(function(data) {
                 $scope.login.msg  = "Error in Response.";

            });

        },
      $scope.logout = function() {
          // user is logged out
        //  $rootScope.user = null;
     }
    }]);
```

Comment: you need to provide a routeProvider specifying your controller and template for your route url /home. Have a look over here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Have a look at angular-ui-router as well https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router (my personal choice, if applied you can route to the state by $state.go('home') and done.

Comment: @user1653773: Seeing your urgency got a tutorial plunker which will really help you visualize how angular works here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/UkHDqFD8P7tTEqSaCOcc?p=preview Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: will try in the meanwhile have a look at the link provided above hope it helps

Comment: okk thanks :)...i am looking into it..still if possible, try to find out some time to help me

Answer (score -1):

you can store the login information using [$cookieStore or $cookie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore), so in the success what you need to do it put the user auth token in cookie.

please check above link for examples on how to store cookies.

Comment: you dont need $apply, just use $location.path("/home");

Comment: do you want to look at my code? I am very much new in Angular JS..may be i am doing some silly mistake. i really need some help in implementing it. we can connect from team viewer if you are ok with it.

Comment: I have tried that also... $routeprovider itself is creating problem, it is throwing some javascript exception...i imported angular-route.js in my HTML, other than than do i have to do anythinng else to make it work?

Comment: can you please setup a plunker that would be best :)

Comment: Actually it is confidential code..i can't upload it anywhere :(

Comment: that would be really helpful for me..if somebody help me in it...if it starts working after that i can finish it easily..conceptually i understood it but it is my first hands-on that too on live project...thats why asking for some online help :(